# Is $\|e^{zT-zT^*}\|$ bounded for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $E$ be an infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space and $T\in \mathcal{L}(E)$.

> Is $\|e^{zT-zT^*}\|$ bounded for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take $T=iI $. If we write $z=a+ib $, we have $$\|e^{z (T-T^*)}\|=|e^{2iz}|=e^{-2b}, $$ not bounded as we are free to choose $b $.

Note, on the other hand, that  $\|e^{zT-\bar zT^*}\|=1$ for all $z $ (as it is a unitary).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but in your remark I don't understand why $e^{zT-\bar zT^*}$ is unitary?

Comment: Its adjoint is its inverse.

Comment: Thank you very much. it's clear